Example local isometries need not preserve the Riemannian distance
Problem  Suppose $(M, g)$ and $(\tilde{M}, \tilde{g})$ are connected Riemannian manifolds, and $\varphi: M \to \tilde{M}$ is a local isometry. Show that
$
d_{\tilde{g}}(\varphi(p), \varphi(q)) \leq d_g(p, q), \quad p, q \in M.
$
Give an example to show that equality need not hold.
I am looking for an example where local isometries  need not preserve the Riemannian distance
that is where the inequality is strict
Let $M = \mathbb{R}$ with the standard Euclidean metric, and let $\tilde{M} = S^1$ (the circle) with the standard metric. Define the map:
$\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to S^1, \quad \varphi(t) = e^{it},
$

$\varphi$ is a local isometry since it locally preserves the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and the standard metric on $S^1$.
However, globally, the map is not injective, as points in $\mathbb{R}$ separated by multiples of $2\pi$ are mapped to the same point on $S^1$.

For example, consider $p = 0$ and $q = 4\pi$ in $\mathbb{R}$. The Riemannian distance between $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is:
$d_g(0, 4\pi) = 4\pi.
$
However, $\varphi(0) = \varphi(4\pi) = 1 \in S^1$, so the distance between $\varphi(0)$ and $\varphi(4\pi)$ in $S^1$ is:
$
d_{\tilde{g}}(\varphi(0), \varphi(4\pi)) = 0.
$
Thus, in this case:
$
d_{\tilde{g}}(\varphi(0), \varphi(4\pi)) = 0 < 4\pi = d_g(0, 4\pi),
$
showing that equality need not hold when $\varphi$ is not injective.
Does this example work? I am not sure my $\varphi$ is actually a local isometry  , If not, could you give an example that works?**
definitions:



Yes, your $\varphi$ is a local isometry. Your use of language is somewhat sloppy: The map pulls back the metric tensor on $S^1$ to the metric tensor on $\Bbb R$; it does not preserve the two metrics.

@TedShifrin Thank for the answer, I am having trouble to check that, If it a local isometry I would need to  find an interval where the distance is preserve, so $|x-y|=d_\tilde g(e^{ix}, e^{iy})$ for all the x,y in that interval, but how would I compute the inf of curves on the right hand side?

What is the definition of a local isometry? (But you can easily show that for $|x-y|<\pi$, the short arc on the circle is the shortest path. Just think about how you establish the shortest path in $\Bbb R$.)

@TedShifrin $g(X,Y)=\varphi^* \tilde{g}(X,Y)= \tilde{g}(d\varphi X, d\varphi Y)$ locally

Precisely. Nothing to do with distances. Just the pullback condition on the metric tensor.

@TedShifrin Yes but  but to check that inequality, i think I still need to find the inf of the integrals that define $d_\tilde g$, otherwise how is it checked?

Your questioning is muddled. You keep saying you need to show $\varphi$ is a local isometry, but that is not what your questions involve. Please reread everything and start over.

@TedShifrin I added the complete text of the problem at the beginning. I need a local isometry so that the the inequality is strict, I though that map could be it, but need to make sure it is a local isometry

As I've said several times, you need to show that $g=\varphi^*\tilde g$, nothing about lengths of paths.
